# Pseudo-element blocks link issue

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, pseudo-element

I used the `:before` pseudo-element to create a bottom border hover animation for my navigation links:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  bottom: 12px;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: transform: 0.2s ease-out;
}

a:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<a>Link 1</a>
<a>Link 2</a>
<a>Link 3</a>
```

The runnable code above does not have this issue but on my website the 2 px thick border of the pseudo-element blocks the menu link and changes the cursor to the default arrow. If the user misclicks on the bottom border, the menu link doesn't work, which creates confusion. And every time you hover past the border, the cursor quickly changes, which makes the navigation menu seem buggy.

Here's a screen recording: https://streamable.com/gk9yir

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ignore pointer at pseudo-element

```
a:before {pointer-events:none;...
```

Answer (score 1):

use box-shadow instead:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:1px;
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  height: 0px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #000;
  bottom: 12px;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: transform: 0.2s ease-out;
}

a:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<a>Link 1</a>
<a>Link 2</a>
<a>Link 3</a>
```

This should fix it since shadows don't take the mouse focus.